# ngb-pagination: page set to 1 when collectionSize retrive

Tags: angular-bootstrap, angular9

At angular 9, page no. reset when update collectionSize asynchronously. Code shown in below,

```
<ngb-pagination class="d-flex justify-content-end"
                  [collectionSize]="total | async"
                  [(page)]="page"
                  [pageSize]="pageSize | async"
                  [maxSize]="5"
                  [boundaryLinks]="true"
                  (pageChange)="pageChanged($event)"></ngb-pagination>
```

It was working fine if collectionSize didn't update.
Any solution here?